# Hide div when contents of another div have loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an image that loads as a series of slices inside a div. I only want to display the div after all its contents have loaded. I'm using another div to mask the div that's loading:

```html
<div id="prepage" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; background-color:white; height:100%; width:100%; z-index:1">
  <div align="center">
    <p>loading... please wait</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to hide the above div when the images in div id="graphic" have loaded. I was thinking something like this might work:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#prepage").hide();
});
```

However it's not working. This seems a relatively common question, but for some reason none of the answers work for me - probably because my coding skills are rudimentary. Thanks in advance.

*update* it seems I should have included the contents of the image div:

```html
<div align="center" id="graphic">
  <div style="position:relative; left:0px; top:0px; width:251px; height:350px">
 <div style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:251px; height:8px;">
  <img src="foo.gif" width="251" height="8" alt="">
 </div>
 <div style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:3px; width:96px; height:12px;">
  <img src="bar.gif" width="96" height="12" alt="">
 </div>
```

^ and so on. There's 25 gif slices that make up the entire image in the div.

Comment: Not much to do when we don't know anything about the `div id="graphic"` element

Comment: Sorry, it was a lot of html that I didn't think was relevant beyond my description. Will amend the question.

Comment: Replace the content of the loading div with the code of loaded images.

Comment: so `bar.gif` and `foo.gif` are loaders?

Comment: foo.gif and bar.gif are just 2 of the 25 image slices that are assembled in a larger css table. I'm using slices because the larger image has rollovers that replace images within it.

Comment: what happen when one of the images fails to load?

Comment: Currently, nothing except show a broken ink on the page. I can't even perform a simple div show/hide using jquery.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] and we'll be able to see what goes wrong.

Comment: The code in my question works if I place the jquery script at the end of the html.

Answer (score 3):

Hide the div initially, and attach an onload event to the images.

Create a data attribute that increases for each image loaded, then show the div when it equals the total number of images:

```
$('#graphic img').on('load', function() {
  let loaded = ($('#graphic').data('loaded') + 1) || 1;
  $('#graphic').data('loaded', loaded);
  if (loaded == $('#graphic img').length) {
    $('#graphic').show();
  }
});
```

```js
$('#graphic img').on('load', function() {
  let loaded = ($('#graphic').data('loaded') + 1) || 1;
  $('#graphic').data('loaded', loaded);
  if (loaded == $('#graphic img').length) {
    $('#graphic').show();
  }
});
```

```css
#graphic {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" id="graphic">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/51?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/52?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/53?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/54?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/55?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/56?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/57?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/58?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/59?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/60?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/61?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/62?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/63?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/64?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/65?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/66?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/67?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/68?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/69?random">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I could get your code to work, but when I started adding mine, I lost the functionality. However, what I learned in the process was that I had my script in the wrong place. In the end, I got it working just by using my original jquery code, but placing it at the end of the html.